# How can i continuously get a html-videos current time?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying in js to get a videos current time. I have come up with a rather ugly and not so precise solution, using a `setInterval` on the `play` event. But i would very much prefer using a better method. Maybe `requestAnimationFrame` could do it? I'm open for a better solution.

Current code:

```
  this.video = document.createElement('video')
  this.duration = null
  this.currentTime = null

  this.video.addEventListener('play', this.play)

  play(e) {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.currentTime = this.video.currentTime
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Comment: Use the `timeupdate` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [`timeupdate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event).

Example:

```js
let video = document.getElementById("video");
let currentTime = null;

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdate);

function timeUpdate(e) {
  currentTime = e.target.currentTime;
  console.log("Time: " + currentTime);
}
```

```html
<video id="video" width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```